# Login panel issue

Tags: php

I am having two login panels. 1st with only username and password and 2nd with username, password and two user types as radio buttons. how can I write function for both login panels? I have written following function for the same.

```
function _check_user($username,$password,$user_type)
{
    $query= 'SELECT * FROM ' . USERS_TABLE . ' WHERE login =  $username AND  password =$password AND user_type =$user_type';
    $r = $db->query ($query);   
    if ($db->numrows($r)==1)
    {
        $f = $db->fetcharray($r);
        if ($f['login'] == $username && $f['password'] == $password && $f['user_type']=="$user_type")
            $logged = TRUE;
        else 
            $logged = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $logged = FALSE;
    }
    return $logged;
}
```

Comment: I hope you're not storing passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [default argument values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

```
function _check_user($username, $password, $user_type = null) { ... }
```

It will allow you use the function with or without the `$user_type` argument e.g.

```
_check_user('user', 'pass');
_check_user('user', 'pass', 'type');
```

You will need to refactor your code to take into account that `$user_type` could be `null`.

```
$userAndPassValid = $f['login'] == $username && $f['password'] == $password;
$userTypeValid = true;

if ($user_type != null) {
    $userTypeValid = $f['user_type'] == $user_type;
}

if ($userAndPassValid && $userTypeValid) {
    // proceed
}
```

Comment: Hi Buddy.. I have tried this and written the below function but not working for me.. could you please suggest me any changes needed for below...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value for $user_type= "something" at startup only.
After clicking login button you check the value of $user_type is predefined or changed and accordingly write your query

Comment: function auth_check_user1($login,$password,$agent=null)
{
$userAndPassValid=($f['login']==$login && $f['password']==$password);
$userTypeValid = true;      
if ($agent !='') { proceed with something}

Comment: elseif($userAndPassValid && $userTypeValid)
{
$sql=SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=$login AND password=$password;
$r = $db->query ($sql);
if($db->numrows($r)==1)
{ proceed with something }